# AWK rounding variable in calculation

Tags: awk, rounding

Not entirely sure why, but either awk is rounding off my variable *x* to 2dp OR the regex pattern to test if integer doesn't work properly.

My code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=972286200; i<=972384300; i=i+900) {x=((i/86400)-0.375); if(x ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) {s=i} printf("%010d,%.3f,%010d\n",i,x,s)}}'
```

Code is trying to create a dataset that has columns like this:

1. *i -* Data incremented by 900
2. *x -* Test if data divides by a number
3. *s -* If the division IS integer, use *i*, if NOT use previous integer *i*

Currently produces:

```
0972286200,11252.938,0000000000
0972287100,11252.948,0000000000
0972288000,11252.958,0972288000
0972288900,11252.969,0972288900
0972289800,11252.979,0972289800
0972290700,11252.990,0972290700
0972291600,11253.000,0972291600
0972292500,11253.010,0972292500
0972293400,11253.021,0972293400
0972294300,11253.031,0972294300
0972295200,11253.042,0972295200
0972296100,11253.052,0972295200
0972297000,11253.062,0972295200
0972297900,11253.073,0972295200
...
...
0972372600,11253.938,0972295200
0972373500,11253.948,0972295200
0972374400,11253.958,0972374400
0972375300,11253.969,0972375300
0972376200,11253.979,0972376200
0972377100,11253.990,0972377100
0972378000,11254.000,0972378000
0972378900,11254.010,0972378900
0972379800,11254.021,0972379800
0972380700,11254.031,0972380700
0972381600,11254.042,0972381600
0972382500,11254.052,0972381600
0972383400,11254.062,0972381600
0972384300,11254.073,0972381600
```

I want it to produce:

```
0972286200,11252.938,0000000000
0972287100,11252.948,0000000000
0972288000,11252.958,0000000000
0972288900,11252.969,0000000000
0972289800,11252.979,0000000000
0972290700,11252.990,0000000000
0972291600,11253.000,0972291600
0972292500,11253.010,0972291600
0972293400,11253.021,0972291600
0972294300,11253.031,0972291600
0972295200,11253.042,0972291600
0972296100,11253.052,0972291600
0972297000,11253.062,0972291600
0972297900,11253.073,0972291600
...
...
0972372600,11253.938,0972291600
0972373500,11253.948,0972291600
0972374400,11253.958,0972291600
0972375300,11253.969,0972291600
0972376200,11253.979,0972291600
0972377100,11253.990,0972291600
0972378000,11254.000,0972378000
0972378900,11254.010,0972378000
0972379800,11254.021,0972378000
0972380700,11254.031,0972378000
0972381600,11254.042,0972378000
0972382500,11254.052,0972378000
0972383400,11254.062,0972378000
0972384300,11254.073,0972378000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the int test with `x==int(x)` instead.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for(i=972286200; i<=972384300; i+=900) 
                {x=(i/86400)-0.375; 
                 if(x==int(x)) s=i; 
                 printf "%010d,%.3f,%010d\n",i,x,s}}'
```

also changed couple minor things.

Comment: Thanks, when I googled I couldn't find the x==int(x) test, just a few examples where people were testing with regex :)

Comment: There is a famous quote for this *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.*